# Choco Install Mongodb throws internal server error 500

Tags: powershell, mongodb, chocolatey, http-status-code-500

I am stuck on installing mongodb with chocolatey.
This is the command I use:

```
choco install mongodb
```

I execute it in powershell with administrative rights.

This is the error (translated from german):

> Remote server returned an error: Internal server error (500). Mongodb not installed. See log for details.

In the log there is showing up the same text. Any ideas?

Comment: There were some issues last night regarding dot org. They have been resolved but we have not identified the root cause so they could crop up again. It should work again now if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: Yes, now it is working. So it was indeed a temporarily problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a temporary issue with Chocolatey.org when it was under heavy load. This has been corrected and the site returned to normal operation.